# How to return multiple values through function

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created the below function that will return workspace details which the loggedin user has access to.

But this function is returning only the first record from the select list.

I need all the records to be displayed as output.

Please modify it and let me know.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "F_WORKSPACE_LOGIN_USERS" (
  p_email VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

  l_error       VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_workspace   VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_teams       VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_team        VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN ( SELECT a.name workspace,
                    a.team_id id
             FROM slackdatawarehouse.teams a,
                  ( SELECT TRIM(workspaces) workspaces
                    FROM alluser_workspaces_fact
                    WHERE lower(email) = lower(p_email)
  ) b
             WHERE a.team_id IN ( SELECT c.team_id
                                  FROM slackdatawarehouse.team_tokens c
  )
                   OR   instr(', '
  || lower(b.workspaces),', '
  || lower(a.name) ) > 0
  ORDER BY 1 ) LOOP
    l_teams := l_team
    || ','
    || i.id;
    l_teams := ltrim(rtrim(l_teams,','),',');
    RETURN l_teams;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Current output is :

T6HPQ5LF7,T6XBXVAA1,T905JLZ62,T7CN08JPQ,T9MV4732M,T5PGS72NA,T5A4YHMUH,TAAFTFS0P,T69BE9T2A,T85D2D8MT,T858U7SF4,T9D16DF5X,T9DHDV61G,T9D17RDT3,T5Y03HDQ8,T5F5QPRK7

Required output is :

```
T6HPQ5LF7
T6XBXVAA1
T905JLZ62
```

i need output like above as one by one

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that code really does (can't test it), but this might be the culprit:

```
    ...
    RETURN l_teams;    
  END LOOP;
```

As soon as code reaches the `RETURN` statement, it exits the loop and ... well, *returns* what's currently in L_TEAMS variable. Therefore, move `RETURN` out of the loop:

```
     ...
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_teams;
```

If it still doesn't work as expected (which might be the case), have a look at *pipelined functions* (for example, on [Oracle-base site](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions#pipelined_table_functions)) as they are designed to return values you seem to be looking for.

A simple example:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_dp_row as object
  2    (deptno number,
  3     dname  varchar2(20));
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_dp_tab is table of t_dp_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function f_depts
  2    return t_dp_tab pipelined
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select deptno, dname from dept)
  6    loop
  7      pipe row(t_dp_row(cur_r.deptno, cur_r.dname));
  8    end loop;
  9    return;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(f_depts);

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS

SQL>
```

Comment: yes i can use this but could you please give some ex without using cursor but bit confusing, i also tried putting the retuen statement outside the loop then also doesnt works

Comment: also i am getting error for using the pipeline [unsupported data type]

Comment: create or replace FUNCTION  "F_WORKSPACE_LOGIN_USERS" (p_email varchar2)  
return t_dp_tab pipelined is

l_error  varchar2(1000);
l_workspace varchar2(1000);
begin
for i in (select a.name workspace,a.team_id id from slackdatawarehouse.teams a,(select trim(WORKSPACES) WORKSPACES
from ALLUSER_WORKSPACES_FACT where lower(email)=lower(p_email)) b
where  a.team_id in (select c.team_id from slackdatawarehouse.team_tokens c) or
instr(', '||lower(b.WORKSPACES),', '||lower(a.name)) > 0 order by 1) loop
pipe row(t_dp_row(i.id));
end loop;
return ;
end;

Comment: now i am getting output asT6HPQ5LF7,T6XBXVAA1,T905JLZ62,T7CN08JPQ,T9MV4732M,T5PGS72NA,T5A4YHMUH,TAAFTFS0P,T69BE9T2A,T85D2D8MT,T858U7SF4,T9D16DF5X,T9DHDV61G,T9D17RDT3,T5Y03HDQ8,T5F5QPRK7 but i need output should be one by one

Comment: Concatenate CHR(10) at the end of each line (if that's what you're asking).

Comment: Google "oracle pipelined function"

Comment: @Stew, that's what my example does.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I was trying to point the OP to where they could find other examples of what they're looking for. You were really generous to write it all out for them.